# "NULL may be passed instead, to reset this handler to its default state."

Tags: php, exception

In the documentation for [`set_exception_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php), at the end of the `exception_handler` parameter description it says the following:

> NULL may be passed instead, to reset this handler to its default state.

...what does that mean?

1. In what cases does this happen?
2. And what should the handler exactly do in that case exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* the documentation is referring to passing `null` to the `set_exception_handler` function, not as a parameter to the user-defined callback.  The callback should never receive a null parameter.

Passing `null` to `set_exception_handler` resets to PHP's built-in exception handling.  It seems to be the equivalent of calling `restore_exception_handler`.

Let's test it out:

```
<?php
$eh = function($err) { echo 'Here'; };
set_exception_handler($eh);
throw new \Exception('Problem');
```

Output:

> Here

And now with `null`:

```
<?php
$eh = function($err) { echo 'Here'; };
set_exception_handler($eh);
set_exception_handler(null);
throw new \Exception('Problem');
```

Output:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Problem' in ...
>
> Stack trace: ...

Comment: Ooooh, that actually does make sense. Thank you 